# Yii2 Kartik Expendable column. How do i load only on expand?

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

I added Kartik Expandable column to my grid. But it takes a while to load because its loading every expandable data of each row. Is it possible to load expandable data only on expand click ?

Comment: Check `detailUrl` in [documentation](https://demos.krajee.com/grid#expand-row-column)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.